Fresh install of laravel with Dockerfile locally does not show laravel page
I'm mostly following this guide https://www.bomberbot.com/web-development/how-to-run-laravel-on-google-cloud-run-with-continuous-integration-a-step-by-step-guide/ to dockerize and locally run a fresh install of the Laravel app but when I try http://localhost:8080 I get ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
I got a fresh Laravel install from: composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel my-laravel-app
where
$ php artisan --version
Laravel Framework 11.35.1

My Dockerfile
FROM php:8.2-apache

WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY composer.lock composer.json ./

ADD https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/releases/latest/download/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && sync && \
    install-php-extensions mbstring pdo_mysql zip exif pcntl gd

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl \
    lua-zlib-dev \
    libmemcached-dev libonig-dev \
    libzip-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg && docker-php-ext-install gd

COPY . .

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/storage /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache
RUN chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/storage /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN useradd -G www-data,root -u 1000 -d /home/devuser devuser
RUN mkdir -p /home/devuser/.composer && \
    chown -R devuser:devuser /home/devuser

RUN composer install #--no-dev --no-interaction --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader

RUN php artisan config:clear

EXPOSE 8080

CMD bash -c "php artisan config:clear && apache2-foreground"

And for the docker commands I ran
docker build -t my-laravel-app-1 .
docker run --init -d -e PORT=8080 -p 8080:8080 my-laravel-app-

So when I run docker container ls I get
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE              COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                            NAMES
d601e608d71a   my-laravel-app-1   "docker-php-entrypoi…"   9 minutes ago   Up 9 minutes   80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   confident_ptolemy

Which looks right to me but I keep getting empty responses at http://localhost:8080.
Is that expected for a fresh Laravel install? I was expecting the Laravel page.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The php:apache image variants normally listen on the standard HTTP port 80, it looks like.  Does using this as the second -p port number help; -p 8080:80?  (You can delete the ineffective Dockerfile EXPOSE line.)

Thanks that helped! It gave me a different error -- turns out the Dockerfile had to be updated it didn't contain some needed lines

Do you know how to set that in the Dockerfile itself instead of as a command line argument when bringing up the docker image?

You can't, you must use a docker run -p option or similar.  Also see How to publish ports in docker files?
